# Populating Java Menu's with for loops

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I'm trying to create a GUI application, but I want to keep code clean and easy to understand. It is my desire to have a menubar with 2 Menu's which contain Menu's which contain JMenuItems. Hence trying to go with a for loop. I ran into a problem that I could not identify my created JMenuItems, so adding listeners to them would become rather difficult.

My code is as follows:

```
JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar;
JMenu theorie = new JMenu("Theorie");
String[] ChapterContainer   = new String[]  {"Hoofdstuk 1","Hoofdstuk 2","Hoofdstuk 3","Hoofdstuk 4","Hoofdstuk 5","Hoofdstuk 6","Hoofdstuk 7","Hoofdstuk 8","Hoofdstuk 9","Hoofdstuk 10"};
String[] ParContainer       = new String[]  {"Paragraaf 1","Paragraaf 2","Paragraaf 3","Paragraaf 4","Paragraaf 5"};
String[] ChapterVars        = new String[]  {"h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7","h8","h9","h10"};
String[] ParVars            = new String[]  {"p1","p2","p3","p4","p5"};

for(int i = 0 ; i<ChapterVars.length ; i++){
    JMenu ChapterVars[i] = new JMenu(ChapterContainer[i]);

    for(int j = 0 ; j<ParVars.length ; j++){
    JMenuItem ParVars[j] = new JMenuItem(ParContainer[j]);
    // ActionListener code here
    ChapterVars[i].add(ParVars[j]);
    }
    theorie.add(ChapterVars[i]);
}
menubar.add(theorie);
```

Am I going about this in the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Action`s instead, these are self contained units of work, see [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details.

Comment: I don't recommend it, but, the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` method will return the text of the button (or `JMenuItem` in this case) when no `actionCommand` property is set on the button.

Comment: You have ParVars defined as a String array, then in the inner loop try to set parVars[j] to be a JMenuItem. this should  cause compile errors.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. You first two variables are correct, the other are not. Notice how the forum highlights them differently? Be consistent!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are clearly going in the right direction. To enable people to help you quickly, please make sure your code compiles and gives a short demonstration of your question (see [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice).

The [Java Tutorials - How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) section has a nice example on how to create menus.

The `ChapterVars` and `ParVars` arrays can be removed if you add the menus and menu items directly to the structure. Taking the remarks of [FredK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971422/fredk) and [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) into account (but leaving the change to use `Action`s to you), your code could look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopulatingJavaMenus {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new PopulatingJavaMenus().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu theorie = new JMenu("Theorie");

        String[] chapterContainer   = new String[]{
                "Hoofdstuk 1","Hoofdstuk 2","Hoofdstuk 3","Hoofdstuk 4","Hoofdstuk 5",
                "Hoofdstuk 6","Hoofdstuk 7","Hoofdstuk 8","Hoofdstuk 9","Hoofdstuk 10"};

        String[] parContainer       = new String[]{
                "Paragraaf 1","Paragraaf 2","Paragraaf 3","Paragraaf 4","Paragraaf 5"};

        for (final String chapterText : chapterContainer) {
            JMenu chapterMenu = new JMenu(chapterText);
            for (String paragraphText : parContainer) {
                // ActionListener code here
                chapterMenu.add(new JMenuItem(paragraphText));
            }
            theorie.add(chapterMenu);
        }
        menubar.add(theorie);

        return menubar;
    }
}
```